Terraform error while creating a Blob Storage with a Private Endpoint 403
I have an error while trying to create a Blob Storage container with a private endpoint, while the Storage Account is "correctly" created, I get the following error
Error: checking for existing Container "my-container-name"  (Account "Account \"mystorageaccountname\" (IsEdgeZone false / ZoneName \"\" / Subdomain Type \"blob\" / DomainSuffix \"core.windows.net\")"): executing request: unexpected status 403 (403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation.) with AuthorizationFailure: This request is not authorized to perform this operation

I have already review the permissions of the assigned roled to the Storage Account, my Terraform user has the correct permissions to perform all actions to create, modify and such cloud resources.
Here is the storage account, container, and blob storage configuration:
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                            = "${local.lower_service_name}${local.lower_slug_environment}storage"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  account_tier                    = "Standard"
  account_replication_type        = "LRS" # Locally Redundant Storage
  account_kind                    = "StorageV2"
  public_network_access_enabled   = false
  default_to_oauth_authentication = true
  https_traffic_only_enabled      = true
  min_tls_version                 = "TLS1_2"

  blob_properties {
    versioning_enabled            = true
    change_feed_enabled           = true
    change_feed_retention_in_days = 90
    last_access_time_enabled      = true
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 90
    }

    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "main" {
  storage_account_id         = azurerm_storage_account.main.id
  default_action             = "Deny"
  ip_rules                   = []
  bypass                     = ["AzureServices"]
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [module.storage_account_subnet.subnets_information["private-${local.service_name}-StorageAccount-1"].id]
}
# tfsec:ignore:azure-storage-no-public-access
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "main" {
  name                  = "${local.lower_service_name}-${local.lower_environment}-storage-container"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.main.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "main" {
  name                   = "${local.lower_service_name}-${local.lower_environment}"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.main.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.main.name
  type                   = "Block"
  access_tier            = "Hot"
}

I have already tried using ChatGPT, Terraform Azure provider documentation, even a Chinese website that I found where they claim to have the solution to this specific problem, which they don't, also, and lastly, Azure Documentation which is kinda confusing and not straightforward

You deny the permission for public access on your storage account which means your own machine was also get blocked for access even though you have all the permissions. So to create a container your machine network should be in the same private endpoint virtual network range. That should be done from different machine mentioned in virtual network range @JoseAngelBadillo

I understand, the thing is that even allowing public access I haven't been able to create it, I get the same error 403 :(

have you cheched with this stack links i shared in the solution @joseangelbadilio

have you got the chance to review the solution provided? Is there anything I can do on my end to assist further? @JoséAngelBadillo


Terraform error while creating a Blob Storage with a Private Endpoint 403

Initially when I tried the configuration which you shared mentioning that the public access on storage account was disabled. Even I faced the same error you mentioned.

This is mainly due to entire configuration till container creation was placed under same configuration file. Where you created the storage account with public access disabled and still try to access the container inside it form different IP range that you mentioned in the Private endpoint virtual network.
In order to overcome the issue, we have three different approaches

Allow your own IP to access the storage account so that you alone can access the storage account as youre the one provisioning the storage account as mentioned in Stack link this will allow your IP and the vnet range mentioned in the private end point for the preexiting storage account.

If you want to access the storage account without any public network we need to access via private end point used by newly created VM from a different configuration file.

If you want to use the same configuration to create the storage account with private end point and container provision using the same terraform file then follow the Stack link answered by me where you need to add your own IP to firewall rules


Refer:
Tutorial: Connect to a storage account using an Azure Private Endpoint - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn
